# Проверить последнюю букву в слове

Tags: java

Привет! Не подскажите как сделать проверку последней буквы слова/строки.Дескать, если последняя буква - б(или люба другая), то выведем это слово, например.

Никак на ум решение не приходит...

P.S

Не могли бы вы еще подсказать, как проверить окончание не по одной букве, а по нескольким...

Заранее благодарствую!

Comment: А документацию к классу String почитать вам на ум тоже не приходит?

Comment: О! Вот что документация животворящая делает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

endsWith("а") - ?